# Spring CLI issues - unable to list spring cloud services in CLI

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cli

I did this

```
D:\pcf>spring --version
Spring CLI v2.0.6.RELEASE
```

and

```
spring install org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-cli:2.0.0.RELEASE
```

Now

```
D:\pcf>spring cloud --list
```

gives

```
Oct 18, 2018 2:15:57 PM org.springframework.cloud.launcher.cli.LauncherCommand$LauncherOptionHandler run
SEVERE: Error running spring cloud
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.cloud.launcher.cli.LauncherCommand$LauncherOptionHandler.run(LauncherCommand.java:115)
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.options.OptionHandler.run(OptionHandler.java:84)
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.OptionParsingCommand.run(OptionParsingCommand.java:54)
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.CommandRunner.run(CommandRunner.java:219)
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.CommandRunner.runAndHandleErrors(CommandRunner.java:171)
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.SpringCli.main(SpringCli.java:63)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot locate library: C:\Users\RZHHHN/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/experimental/spring-boot-thin-launcher/1.0.12.RELEASE/spring-boot-thin-launcher-1.0.12.RELEASE-exec.jar
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.wrapper.ThinJarWrapper.launch(ThinJarWrapper.java:120)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.wrapper.ThinJarWrapper.main(ThinJarWrapper.java:97)
        ... 18 more
```

I tried some "clean up" of .m2 but no help